# What is the significance of God positioning his throne above the earth?

Tags: earth

The Book of Isaiah 40:22 provides information on where God's throne is, in proximity to the earth.

**Isaiah 40:22**

> It is he who sits above the circle of the earth

This verse gives us information on where God's throne is because God sits on a throne but that throne is above the circle of the earth according to Prophet Isaiah. The verse is also accurate in that it validates the shape of the earth as proposed by science as being a circle or an ellipse(it is a sphere). Is there any significance why God decided to position his throne close to the earth given how big the universe is?

Since God is everywhere in the universe at all times then establishing his throne in some other place wouldn't have made a difference,  why did he decide to position his throne close to the earth? Was it because he needed to be close to his creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this graphic illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_cosmology#/media/File:Early_Hebrew_Conception_of_the_Universe.svg) of the Biblical cosmology as imagined by the authors of the Bible, including Isaiah, explaining what they meant by "circle of the earth" which **includes** the stars, the sun, and the moon.  So while modern astronomy's earth stops at the outer edge of earth's atmosphere, their earth extends to the whole universe.

You are right that God wants to be close to his creation (["God with us"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel) is a very important doctrine), but your assertion that God decides "to position his throne close to [modern notion of planet] earth" is false.

Rather, taking into account modern astronomy's findings about the vastness of the universe, as modern Christians we conceptualize the location of God's throne *not* as close to the universe's edge (which is millions of light years away), but in **another dimension APART from our universe** (transcendent).  But God is also **WITHIN our universe** (immanent) so God can be **close to us NOT in geographical / astronomical terms**, but in these ways:

1. in our conscience
2. in the operation of his creatures, i.e. the innate *telos* / instinct that "move" all creatures according to their distinct natures (mountains vs. vegetation vs. animal vs. human)
3. to sustain us in being (i.e. our very existence in this universe)
4. in being present within our souls for those who choose to be born again by giving us His Trinitarian Life

Comment: Very present in our conscience because he tells us when we do something wrong